Generate pyi stubfile for not importable C module
I have a package A that uses a special package A.B, both are 3rd and 4th party packages written in C using Boost. Because it there is some special setup A.B is not included as a submodule but only as a some variable. Both import A.B and also first import A then import A.B fail with a ModuleNotFoundError.
Only the following two ways work to access B.
# OK
import A
A.B # -> <module: B>

# OK
from A import B
B # -> <module: B>

# ModuleNotFoundError
import A.B

B again is a nested package, e.g. with B.x.y.z, B.a.b, ...

I would like to create stub files for A.B, however pyright --createstub or mypy's stubgen relies on import A.B and therefore fails.
There exists a useful answer to write a simple parser, however as I have to deal with properties, overloads, cross-imports extending it feels like reinventing the wheel and many cases need custom handling.
I assume that mypy's stubgen --inspect-mode code could be modified or used with a debugger to provide the module directly instead of trying to import it and using it afterwards.
This is where I am stuck. How can modify stubgen or any other stub generator to get it to work with such a module?

EDIT: Further notes:
after importing A, B and all submodules are recursively added to sys.modules without any dot-path, i.e. import A; import B works if performed in that order.

I also tried pybind11-stubgen but it seems to not work well with Boost and I receive many errors trying to use it.

If import A loads all the subpackages, does import A.B after import A work? If so, consider writing a wrapper over stubgen to just run import A before anything else.

Sadly no. import A.B never works in this case here.

That's very strange - it implies that the packages don't follow the Python module specifications properly. I guess even if you run from A import B, running sys.modules["A.B"]  results in a KeyError? What does running A.B.__name__ show?

Great intuition: A.B.__name__ shows me "B". sys.modules["A.B"] raises a KeyError. However, I realized that checking sys.modules after import A contains keys for B, (B.)x, (B.x).y. [Wow thats messy] So I can do import A; import B; import x, if I first import A.

Yep, this is messy - in a normal package layout, A.B.__name__ should show "A.B". You'll basically have to write a wrapper around stubgen where the first import statement (apart from from __future__ import <...>) needs to point to a module which loads an import hook, and the import hook reinterprets how imports work when the source module starts with the name A.. Or better yet, get the upstream fixed :). Good luck!
